# iMacros Element Not Found, how do I refresh page until element appears?

Tags: javascript, runtime-error, imacros

I have a very simple iMacro for Firefox and all I want it to do is refresh a page until a missing element is found.

VERSION BUILD=8601111 RECORDER=FX 
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=http://fieldguided.bigcartel.com/product/light-as-a-feather-ice-cave
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:product_form ATTR=ID:add_to_cart

I get the error:
RuntimeError: element BUTTON specified by ID:add_to_cart was not found, line: 5 (Error code: -921)

How do I refresh the page until the button ID:add_to_cart appears?

Answer (score 0):

```
VERSION BUILD=8601111 RECORDER=FX 
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=http://fieldguided.bigcartel.com/product/light-as-a-feather-ice-cave
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:product_form ATTR=ID:add_to_cart
```

Use this code. There are few other things to think about but it can't be done without JavaScript scripting. Search on stackoverflow how to make JavaScript iMacros macro.